# Problem with pluralization of translations in Django

Tags: django, internationalization, translation, gettext

Hello I'm trying to pluralize the following text

```
<p>{% trans "How much apples do I have? I have " %}
{{ nb_apples }} 
{% blocktrans count nb_apples=1 %}apple{% plural %}apples{% endblocktrans %}</p>
```

My .po file is defined like that

```
#: .\templates\pages\home.html:13
msgid "apple"
msgid_plural "apples"
msgstr[0] "pomme"
msgstr[1] "pommes"
```

But the above doesn't work.

With
count nb_apples=1 or count nb_apples=0 it never pluralize

With
count nb_apples>1 it produces a syntax error

With
count nb_apples=1|length it always pluralizes but the singular is not respected when I only get one apple. Notice that the nb_apples variable is randomly passed from the view like that

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs) 
    context['title'] = _('Home')
    context['comment'] = _('Welcome to my site')
    context['posts'] = posts
    context['nb_apples'] = random.randint(1,10)
    return context
```

and that, after the class

```
def home(request): 
    nb_apples = random.randint(1,10)
    return render(request, 
                  'pages/home.html', 
                  {
                    'title': _('Home'),
                   'comment': _('Welcome to my site'),
                   'nb_apples': nb_apples
                })
```

I want to see "apple" or "pomme" when the nb_apples variable is equal to 1 and "apples" or "pommes" when the nb_apples variable is greater than 1.

What's wrong?

Comment: In general: it is much better (and less similar to "Google translations") if you translate separately the case of 0, 1, 2, and n>2.